# VB.NET / VB - Passing a variable into Startinfo.Arguments

Tags: vb.net, string, variables

I'm trying to use a string variable in StartInfo.Arguments of a process, but can't figure out the correct syntax.

```
 Dim pquery As New Process
    Dim User As String = "test"
    pquery.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    pquery.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    pquery.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    pquery.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c dsquery.exe * -filter ""(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)(mail=***string variable should go here***)))"" | dsget user -samid"
    pquery.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    pquery.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    pquery.Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28VS.96%29.aspx):

Change your assignment to `pquery.StartInfo.Arguments` like so:

```
pquery.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/c dsquery.exe * -filter ""(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)(mail={0})))"" | dsget user -samid", User)
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  If you werent in my family tree and were an attractive single female, I'd have your babies.

Comment: Glad to help (and glad to *not* be able to help with the baby)!